# VideoSDK api is not working on deployment server

Tags: asp.net, videosdk.live

I'm using VideoSDK api on Angular + ASP.NET project.
It's working fine on my local, but on deployment server, it's not working.

I've deployed sample react project that cloned from VideoSDK documentation to the smarterasp.net, but not working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced with the same problem when I was working with VideoSDK API.
Try to integrate ssl.

Comment: you mean make site as https://?

Comment: yes you have to make it as https